# can i create second Put request in RestApi only for changing password?

Tags: c#, angular, rest

I m trying to pass changePasswordDto to RestApi, i created 2nd Put request

```
[HttpPut("updatePassword")]
    public ActionResult<User> Put([FromBody] ChangePasswordDto newPass)
    {

            return Ok("Hi Boy");

    }
```

In angular it looks like that:

```
changePassword(newPass: string) {
this.currentUserId = this.authService.getUserID();
this.changePasswordDto = {
  newPW: newPass,
  userId: this.currentUserId
}
return this.http.put<any>(environment.apiURL + '/api/user/updatePassword', this.changePasswordDto);
```

}

i put a breakpoint to restApi but it doest go there. when i m checking in postman its allgood, https://localhost:44375/api/user/updatePassword works and hits breakpoint in Controller. Why it doesnt go to api from angular. Thanks

Comment: Are you subscribing to the return of that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `http.put` returns an Observable, it won't be executed until you `.subscribe` to it.

```
this.http.put<any>(environment.apiURL + '/api/user/updatePassword', this.changePasswordDto)
    .subscribe(response => /* do something here */ );
```